# Can't get str_pad() to properly replace characters in a string

Tags: php

I'm trying to replace some characters from a string using `str_pad` and I can't get it to work at all and I have no idea why it doesn't work.

Code:

```
<?php
$t = "abcdefghij";
$t = str_pad($t, 4, "0");
echo $t;
?>
```

Expected:

```
abcd000000
```

Result:

```
abcdefghij
```

I also tried:

```
$t = sprintf("%04x", $t);
```

Which results in:

```
0000
```

Comment: what is your expected result?

Comment: You might want to take a look at preg_replace()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a variable length string, you can use the below

```
$str = "abcdefghijzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz";

$head = substr($str, 0, 4); // construct the first part of your string
$tail = substr($str, 4); // get the second part of the string

print $head . str_repeat('0',strlen($tail));

// or all in one go
$number = 4;
print substr($str, 0, $number) . str_repeat('0',strlen(substr($str, $number)));

//will output
//abcd0000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

To replace everything except the first `x` number of characters in your string.

Answer (score 2):

Because your string is longer than four characters so [`str_pad()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) will not append anything to it.

> If the value of pad_length is negative, less than, or equal to the length of the input string, no padding takes place, and input will be returned.

If you want to always append four zeros just concatenate them onto your string:

```
<?php
$t = "abcdefghij";
$t = '0000' . $t;
echo $t;
?>
```

Comment: Then I've misunderstood the purpose of the function. What I'm trying to get is: `abcd000000`

Comment: Than do `$t = $t . '00000';` But your ultimate issue is the string length.

Answer (score 1):

You need a different functions.  `str_pad()` adds to the string and you are wanting to replace:

```
$t = substr_replace($t, str_repeat('0', strlen($t)-4), 4);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a mixture of `str_pad` and `substr`, using the two like this:

```
echo str_pad(substr($str, 0, 4), strlen($str), '0', STR_PAD_RIGHT);
```

Will give you output like this:

```
abcd000000
```

You may however, need to tweak the numbers to get your desired results.

Here is a function you can use:

```
function pad($str, $length, $value= '0', $side = STR_PAD_RIGHT){
    return str_pad(substr($str, 0, $length), strlen($str), $value, $side);
}

echo pad('abcdefghij', 4);
```